# Telerik RadGrid autopostback when row is selected

Tags: telerik-grid

I have a RadGrid with KeyboardNavigation allowed, RowSelection enabled.

When i click on a row using the mouse, the post back happens and i perform the necessary operations that i wish to do.

Now, when i use the keyboard up/down keys to change the row selection, the grid does change the SelectedRow (the display shows the selection happening). But the control does not post back in this case.

Anybody know how to create a postback after a row is changed by the keyboard?

Answer (score -1):

jai telengana

```
function keyPress(sender, args) {

    if (args.get_keyCode() == 13) {
        args.set_cancel(true);
        if (sender._activeRow) {
            sender._activeRow.click();
        }
    }
}

<telerik:RadGrid ID="Manage_Group_RadGrid" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" OnItemCommand="Manage_Group_RadGrid_ItemCommand"  AllowPaging="true" AllowMultiRowSelection="true"  OnItemDataBound="Manage_Group_RadGrid_ItemDataBound" ShowStatusBar="true"
    AllowSorting="true" OnDataBinding="Manage_Group_RadGrid_DataBinding"  OnNeedDataSource="Manage_Group_RadGrid_NeedDataSource"  GroupingEnabled="true" ShowGroupPanel="true" OnGroupsChanging="Manage_Group_RadGrid_GroupsChanging"
    PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true" 
    PageSize="15" Height="440px"
    DataKeyNames="cn" runat="server">
    <EditItemStyle BackColor="green" />
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="cn" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true" GroupsDefaultExpanded="false" CommandItemDisplay="Top">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="cn" HeaderText="cn" SortExpression="cn" UniqueName="cn" 
                ItemStyle-Width="200px" HeaderStyle-Width="200px" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="cn" HeaderText="sAMAccountName" SortExpression="sAMAccountName" UniqueName="sAMAccountName"
                ItemStyle-Width="200px" HeaderStyle-Width="200px" />
        </Columns>
        <CommandItemSettings ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" />
    </MasterTableView>
    <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />
    <GroupingSettings ShowUnGroupButton="true"></GroupingSettings>
    <ClientSettings AllowKeyboardNavigation="true" EnablePostBackOnRowClick="false">
        **<ClientEvents OnKeyPress="keyPress" />**
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```